# Insert Drop down Value to a multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a table inside a form

```
<table id="tablereport2" 
class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead style="background-color:black; font-weight:bold; 
        color:aliceblue">
                <tr>

            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Class ID</th>
                <th>Course Title</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>SID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Minutes</th>
            </tr>

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr id="texbox">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].ClassID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ClassID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].CourseTitle)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].CourseTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Department)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Department)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].SID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].SID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].FullName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].FullName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Minutes, new { 
         placeholder = "0", id = "minutes" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
         model[i].Minutes)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="Save" id="btn-submit" 
                 class="btn btn-default" />
                    <span>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Class", "Class",
                      new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-md insertBtn", 
                 StartTime = Dat
```

I want to populate the textbox using the drop-down menu that I have in the upper right corner.

Rite now works but just populate the first one doesn't go through the loop.

```
<td align="right">
<b>@Html.Label("Select Minutes :")</b>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

My Java Script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        var minutes = $(this).val();
        $('#minutes').val(minutes);
    });
});
```

Any Idea guys I would like to do this the simplest way possible.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like you are setting all input ids to the same id `#minutes`. You can only have one, that's why it stops at the first. Is this supposed to fill all of them at once ?

Comment: yes, that's the idea i want to give the users the option to select the time for the dropdown menu, is just 2 times by default 50 or 100, would be easier than enter the time one by one

Comment: Just use a class instead of an id and change your selector accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `minute` id for your elements so it will just stop after the first match since id elements must be unique. Add a `minutes` class instead and you are set.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    var minutes = $(this).val();
    if (minutes != "")
      $('.minutes').val(minutes);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="minutes" /><br/>
<input class="minutes" /><br/>
<input class="minutes" /><br/>
<input class="minutes" /><br/>

<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments ids should be unique. So using a class instead of an id is what you need.

Change

```
id = "minutes”
```

To

```
class = "minutes”
```

And

```
$('#minutes').val(minutes);
```

To

```
$('.minutes').val(minutes);
```

That’s it!